# Can't seem to be able to click on an element using selenium and python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, xpath-1.0

I am trying to click on the "most helpful first" dropdown list and change it into the newest reviews for android playstore apps.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nintendo.zama&showAllReviews=true

tried multiple methods such as the below method also by finding the class and by xpath but nothing worked.

```
new_comments = driver.find_element_by_link_text('"Most helpful first"').click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element with text as **Most helpful first** and then to `click()` on the element with text as **Newest** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nintendo.zama&showAllReviews=true')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Reviews']//following::span[text()='Most helpful first'][1]"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Reviews']//following::span[text()='Most helpful first'][1]//following::span[text()='Newest']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: play_google_com]

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `find_element_by_link_text` method for the link text.

For instance, consider this page source:

```
<html>
<body>
  <p>Are you sure you want to do this?</p>
  <a href="continue.html">Continue</a>
  <a href="cancel.html">Cancel</a>
</body>
<html>
```

So if you want to click by link text:

```
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Continue')
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text('Conti')
```

**BUT**, In your case, the 'Most helpful first' text is not a link text it is in the `<span>` tag.

So you can use the `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` method or the `driver.find_element_by_xpath` method:

**CSS**:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.KKjvXb > span');
```

**XPATH**:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text() = 'Most helpful first']");
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not this element, you should use other element and use send_keys, to check it you need press F12 and watch for element that highlights "Most helpfull first"  field. it's parrent of that element that you already looking for, for me is something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="MocG8c UFSXYb LMgvRb KKjvXb"]').send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN, Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
```

then you saw another list and you need to find good element from list:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@jsname="wQNmvb"]')[-3].click()
```

I use index -3 because there is 6 elements with that same xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in browser console and execute this using javascript executor::

$x("(//span[text()='Most helpful first'])[1]")[0].click();

Answer (score -1):

I managed to do it this way.

```
dropdown = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]').click()
sleep(2)
new_comments = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fcxH9b"]/div[4]/c-wiz/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/c-wiz/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]').click()
```